# Deleting cached image with the same Uri

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Delete cached image with the same Uri (old cached image always served)

I tried with FFImageLoading  CachedImage.InvalidateCache(_userProfileImagePath, CacheType.All, true);
and set CachingEnabled="False" with regular image

```
               <ImageButton 
                    Command="{Binding SetPageCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding MenuItems[8].TargetType}"
                    BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsProfileImageFound}"
                    x:Name="ImageButtonPhoto"              
                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                    HorizontalOptions="Start"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"              
                    Margin="5"
                >
                    <ImageButton.Source>

                        <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding UserProfileImagePath}"
                                        CachingEnabled="False"/>
                    </ImageButton.Source>

                </ImageButton>
```

Comment: When you know the image is going to change frequently why are you caching it in the first place it just beats the purpose don't you think

Comment: I'm not caching it i even tried to set   CachingEnabled="False" specifically for that .... but some how it will still be cached ! .

Comment: Then you might have to talk to Daniel luberda(Author), He might suggest you a trick or two